# Flot points don't connect

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, flot

I'm trying to make a real time graph that updates every X seconds and then graphs it as time goes on.  The problem I'm having is that when it plots the points, the points aren't connected.  Here's what I have so far:

```
var r = [];

function fetchData() {
var options = {
    lines: { show: true },
    points: { show: true },
    xaxis: { show: false }
};
function doSomething(series)
{   
    r.push(series);
    $.plot($("#xx"), r, options);
}
$.ajax({
  url:      'playersonline.php',
  method:   'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success:  doSomething
});

setTimeout(fetchData, 3000);
}

fetchData();
```

This is what the output looks like currently.
[some pic http://screensnapr.com/e/ra6q70.png](http://screensnapr.com/e/ra6q70.png)

Comment: Are you getting the data format right from ajax? see http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/API.txt

Comment: I don't think the way I'm doing it will work with the format.  Each time the playersonline.php script is called it only returns array(time()*1000, $r['player_count']).  The result is .push()'d into an array.  Is there a way I can set those options within the javascript part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like each of your points is a separate series.  For them to be connected, you need to put all the points in a single array, and give that to Flot as one series.

If you look at Flot's examples, there's one that demonstrates real-time updates of a single series.

Comment: I have figured it out.  This was my poor solution: